# When does a MacBook automatically go into sleep mode?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I've learned about many of power management settings and many apps to take control over it (caffeinate, Amphetamine, etc...)

But, when I go into System Preferences → Battery, there are 2 automatic mode switchers :

- "Turn off display after..." that only turns off the display without putting the mac into sleep mode
- "Schedule" that activate sleep mode on fixed time range.

I also heard that there nothing that prevents the MacBook from going into sleep mode when the lid is closed (and there is no external display plugged in).

If there is no visible automatic sleep mode trigger into the System Preferences, is there a condition that make the Mac go automatically into sleep mode ?

And therefore, what is exactly the purpose of apps like caffeinate and Amphetamine, if there is no automatic sleep ?

Comment: When the system automatically turn off screen it also suspend the Mac except if it is specified battery settings : Check this [page](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchle41a6ccd/mac)